# How to make the " th " appear only once

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, html-table, html-email

Revised:

I have these in my contractEmail.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Send') {

$size= sizeof($_POST['users']);
$i = 0;


$message = NULL;

//    $message = null;
for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++){


$userId = $_REQUEST['users'][$i];

$message .= mailContent($userId);


}

$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'This is a test';
$headers = 'From: xx@live.com.ph' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: xx@live.com.ph' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers  .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n';


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

function mailContent($userId) {


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xx","xx","xx");
$stmt = "SELECT * from CV where idvisa = '$userId'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $stmt);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$fName = $row['fName'];
$lName = $row['lName'];
$visaNumber = $row['visanumber'];
$idNumber = $row['idnumber'];
$statusApp = $row['statusapp'];
$accntVisaPhotoPath = $row['accntVisaPhotoPath'];
$passportPath = $row['passportPath'];
$subdate = $row['subdate'];

$message = "<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Visa Number</th><th>ID Number</th><th>Application Status</th><th>Visa Copy</th><th>Passport Copy</th><th>Date</th>
            </tr>" . "\r\n";
$message .= "<tr>
            <td>$fName $lName</td><td>$visaNumber</td><td>$idNumber</td><td>$statusApp</td><td>$accntVisaPhotoPath</td><td>$passportPath</td><td>$subdate</td>
            </tr>   
            </table>" . "\r\n";
  // OTHER LOGICS GO HERE

return $message;

}
echo "<center>You have sent CV(s) </b><br/><br/><br/><br/>YOU MAY NOW    CLOSE THIS WINDOW</center>";
?>
```

but the problem is, it is not as  expected.  The th is repeating in an email up to 10 th.  How to make the th appeared only once?

This is what I want:

```
|  Name   |   Visa Number   | ID Number   |
| Jurie   |   09254352654   | 5674356747  |
| Alex    |   56756786797   | 5464654545  |
```

Here is my [link](http://www.mntr.workforceint.com/contract.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variables in 11  (Table row). That is the reason of repeating in an email up to 10.

Comment: The same variables on the select single boxes, once selected, the email will be sent to one email.

Comment: It is working, but it has many table header up to 10 of those.

Answer (score 0):

Dont put `select person` in your select-option tag.

PS. you can var_dump($_POST['users']) to check out.

Comment: I have these:

array(10) { [0]=> string(2) "15" [1]=> string(2) "16" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(0) "" }